# Same ssh command gives different results to different local machines

Tags: fedora, openssh

Is this even possible or is there a bug with openssh?

I [had a problem with a compiler](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114588/cannot-compile-code-with-inline-assembly-using-solc-linux-binaries), and to allow the compiler's developer to replicate the result I created a remote server. The crazy thing is me running the same command on the same remote machine with the same user resulted in a different output than his. What could be the cause of this?

So in short, I get a failure when running `ssh root@remote_machine 'command'` and another person runs the command successfully, even though the remote_machine is the same. This is extremely baffling, how could this be?

It also happens when I run this command interactively in `ssh` session.

When I run it from my local machine, it fails:

```
[efe@efeninki ~]$ ssh root@66.42.110.134
root@66.42.110.134's password:

[root@vultr ~]# cd test/
[root@vultr test]# ls
Address.sol  solc-linux-amd64-v0.8.10+commit.fc410830  test.sh
[root@vultr test]# ./solc-linux-amd64-v0.8.10+commit.fc410830 --bin Address.sol
Error: Function "extcodesize" not found.
  --> Address.sol:34:21:
   |
34 |             size := extcodesize(account)
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^

Error: Variable count for assignment to "size" does not match number of values (1 vs. 0)
  --> Address.sol:34:13:
   |
34 |             size := extcodesize(account)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When the other user runs it from a `docker` instance, it succeeds:

```
[efe@efeninki ~]$ sudo docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash
root@437d7edb92fc:/# ssh root@66.42.110.134
root@66.42.110.134's password:

[root@vultr ~]# cd test/
[root@vultr test]# ls
Address.sol  solc-linux-amd64-v0.8.10+commit.fc410830  test.sh
[root@vultr test]# ./solc-linux-amd64-v0.8.10+commit.fc410830 --bin Address.sol

======= Address.sol:Address =======
Binary:
60566050600b82828239805160001a6073146043577f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052600060045260246000fd5b30600052607381538281f3fe73000000000000000000000000000000000000000030146080604052600080fdfea2646970667358221220ebf580f669e9f89d1faea352d4ba1d4ab2d9c9774fda9fb483588d4e9b09eb5564736f6c634300080a0033
```

Comment: The question is whether your command failed when you ran it on an ssh interactive shell on the remote machine, or if it fails only when you run it directly through ssh. Also the output could help us assist you, it's difficult to root cause an issue with so little information. BTW, the title says "different hosts", but the question itself talks about same remote host but different users.

Comment: Possible? Yes. How? Assuming the failure you are referring to relates to the SSH session itself (and not to the execution of `command`), there are a few possible ways; answering requires more information on the error you are getting, which may be gathered from `ssh`'s verbose output (`-v`) and/or, if `remote_machine` is in your control, from the the `sshd`-related log entries.

Comment: It could be as simple as the two accounts having a different shell, but you need to provide some concrete details rather than the current abstraction. Can you repeat the failure with a `command` that you can share with us? Ideally one we can try ourselves

Comment: Alright, so remote machine has a binary named `solc` (Solidity compiler written in C++). Also it has a code file is named `Address.sol`, which has inline assembly in it. Both the binary and the code file is in the `test` directory. The ssh command is `ssh root@remote_machine 'cd test && ./solc --bin Address.sol'`. If I run the ssh command on my PC the compilation fails. If someone else runs it compilation succeeds. The same discrepancy persists even after ssh'ing first and running the command interactively. Video: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmXrXUzNWFHKL2KwCNuPZAVhRYMndg1N8J9XHSHce64My3

Comment: @shalgiuan, first please just copy the command and the output of both tries to your question. Secondly, as I've already asked before, what happens when you `ssh` to the remote machine interactively and run those commands on a `shell` to the remote machine?

Comment: The expected behaviour for binary is to always compile with that given file. After it failed to compile on my PC I created this remote machine so the compiler dev could replicate the issue. I still had the compilation error on the remote machine so expected that the compiler dev could debug that way. But to both our shock he could successfully compile while I couldn't.

Comment: @aviro, here are the commands and outputs on my machine (unexpected behaviour) vs with a docker instance: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYubbtR97tKwsBznvQJ6XeQd1bvuqnPjEYACadzbvri76
Same discrepancy when running it interactively.

Comment: @shalgiuan, you need to addit to your question. People should not read the comments to understand the question, and they also shouldn't follow any links. They should be able get all of the relevant the information from the question itself. You should be as detailed as possible and provide all the relevant information, including the commands and their outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh` has an option to transfer some environment variables from the client to the host (`SendEnv` on the client side `ssh`, `AcceptEnv` on the server side `sshd`). It might be that some environment variables you have on the client side are transferred to the server which causes this problem, and the other user doesn't (or has different configuration in his `ssh_config`).

You should compare the environment in the `ssh` between you and the other user:

```
ssh root@remote_machine 'env'
```

My guess is that you'll see some differences that might impact the different results.

Comment: This is it. `LANG=tr_TR.UTF-8` is triggering the bug with the compiler. Thank you!